# What's the difference between a global variable and a dynmically allocatedv variable in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, global-variables

Assuming you know the value of the variable/pointer at compile time is there any difference between this:

```
int x = 5;

main(){
  ...
}
```

and this:

```
main(){

    int *x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 5;   
    ...
}
```

I know the latter assigns memory to the heap and the former the stack, but a global variable will be stored through out the duration of the program as will things stored in the heap. So is there a functional difference between these two snippets of code?

Comment: Is there a difference? I don't see any similarity (except the `x` name). Moreover, the second snippet is illegal at all..

Comment: The `main()` is no longer legal C.

Comment: You might want to get a C book. This is no tutoring site. What is your **specific** problem and what did you try to find out yourself first?

Comment: 1) The C standard does not enforce an implementation to use a stack, nor a specific implementtion for dynamic memory allocation like a heap. 2) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general. 3) Don't use unnecessary cast or cast you don't fully understand.

Comment: "the former [on] the stack" that would only be true if the variable is a local (automatic) variable, which it does not appear to be, and if the implementation has a stack. In your example `int *x = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));` as you say the requirement is known at compile time, but, a) there is no point in allocating memory for a single `int` dynamically and b) the memory is not allocated until it is required at some point (if at all) during the run time of the program.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The similarity is that you'd have a variable storing 5 available globally through out the program.

Comment: @Olaf I have no specific problem in terms of code. I am just trying to figure out the difference using dynamically allocated memory globally and a global variable globally.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'll note the main() is not legal, but it works when I'm compiling even though it brings up a warning. As for the rest, is the difference that the memory is not allocated until it is required in the second example whereas in the first it's allocated immediately?

Comment: A warning in C should be taken serious! Enable and fix all warning before asking.

Comment: You should not tolerate any compiler warnings - treat them as errors. It's a  fool's errand to say "aw shucks it worked, what the heck do the compiler writers know!". In the first case, the memory will always be allocated, in the second, only if that piece of code is run. Consider that you might need some large arrays at different parts of your program, but not all at the same time. You try to define them all globally, but the program does not have enough memory allocated for them all. So you use dynamic memory allocation, freeing each when you have finished with it.

Comment: @EternalStudent, the names of the variables are the same, but their types are different, their scopes are different, they have different linkage, they have different storage duration, *and* they have different values (the value of `x` in the second snippet is unlikely to be 5; that's what's stored in the space to which the (pointer) value of that `x` points).  As EugeneSh. said, they share nothing but the name.

Comment: also note that your global will be visible across all functions in your code file, whereas `int *x` only has scope in its function (in this case `main`). When the function returns, `int *x` will no longer be in scope. If you have not deallocated that memory or have done nothing to save `x` outside of the function, you will have a memory leak.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If 'int *x'  was declared and given a value outside or 'main' would it have the same scope and storage duration as int x? That is, would 'int *x' and 'int x' both have scope to all functions in that file and would their storage duration last till the entire program was terminated?

Comment: @EternalStudent Changing the question after it's been answered is very bad form. Not to mention the fact that the updated second snippet is not valid C, and won't compile. I'm rolling the edit back.

Comment: @user3386109 I ran that exact code on my computer before I made the edit. Used a printf statement to ensure that 'int *x' had 5 in the memory address it was storing too.

Comment: @EternalStudent You didn't run that exact code, even with the `...` replaced with a `printf`. You can't call `malloc` in global scope, period.

Comment: @user3386109 Not being to use malloc in global scope answers my question. It must have been a coincidence the code ran and printed 5.

Comment: Ok, not sure what code you ran. Perhaps you didn't see that the compile failed, and ran an older version. Stuff happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: In all remarks below, I'm assuming that the code is compiled for and running on a normal everyday commonplace modern desktop computer.

> I know the latter assigns memory to the heap

**True**, `malloc` obtains memory from a region of memory known as the heap.

> and the former the stack

**False**, global variables are not stored on the stack. Initialized global variables have their values stored in the executable. The value is loaded from the executable into the [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment).

> but a global variable will be stored through out the duration of the
>   program

**True**.

> as will things stored in the heap

**False**, memory obtained from `malloc` can be released with `free`. Therefore, items stored in the heap may be temporary. They are not necessarily *"stored through out the duration of the program"*

From the comments:

> The similarity is that you'd have a variable storing 5 available
>   globally through out the program.

**False**, the global variable in the first snippet is available throughout the program. The pointer in the second snippet is local to `main` and is only available to other functions if the pointer is passed as a parameter to those functions. For example, the following won't work (because `foo` has no access to `x`).

```
void foo( void ) {
    printf( "%d\n", *x );
}

int main( void ) {
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 5; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One difference is the scope of the variables. The global variable can be accessed from any function in the program, while the pointer variable in `main()` can only be accessed from that function. To access the memory that it references in another function, it would have to be passed as a parameter to the function (or the variable's address could be put into a global variable).

Another difference is that you can change the address that the pointer variable points to.

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x = 5;   
int *y = x;
x = malloc(sizeof(int));
*x = 10;   // *y still contains 5
```

You can't change the location of a global variable, only change its contents.